# How to fine tune BERT model?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

```
    class BertClassifier(nn.Module):
    #Bert Model for Classification Tasks.
    
    def __init__(self, freeze_bert=False):
        """
        @param    bert: a BertModel object
        @param    classifier: a torch.nn.Module classifier
        @param    freeze_bert (bool): Set `False` to fine-tune the BERT model
        """
        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()
        # Specify hidden size of BERT, hidden size of our classifier, and number of labels
        D_in, H, D_out = 768, 50, 2

        # Instantiate BERT model
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

        # Instantiate an one-layer feed-forward classifier
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(D_in, H),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(H, D_out)
        )

        # Freeze the BERT model
        if freeze_bert:
            for param in self.bert.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
```

I want to know that if we call `bert_classifier = BertClassifier(freeze_bert=False)` which means we are not freezing the weights, so does it implies that we are fine tuning ? Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fine-tuning in general means that you update the model weights along with your task specific layer (For example, a linear layer (or other classification architecture) on top of BERT for classification task.). Thus in general you should not freeze the weights. Henceforth, using `bert_classifier = BertClassifier(freeze_bert=False)` is appropriate for fine-tuning.

Additional note: In practice, some people choose not to update the BERT model weights while training the task specific layer (this in turn reduces the requirement of huge compute power). Here, we can consider that BERT model was used to extract the features or embeddings. In this case, you can use `freeze_bert=True`. And some people update the BERT model weights of few layers on top. It all depends on what exactly you want to do.